# sh: 1: program not found

Tags: shell, perl, programming

I have written a script to execute files one by one by calling a installed program. The same program is executing from terminal, like `procheck abc.pdb`, then it's working fine. But when I execute this program in a Perl script like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
@proc = glob '*.pdb';

foreach $proc (@proc)

{
     system ('procheck $proc 2.0');
}
```

Getting error

```
sh: 1: procheck: not found
```

Comment: have you tried specifying the full path to `procheck` ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that might be issues here. First, with the single-quoted string, the variable is not expanded, so the `system()` call sees the literal string `procheck $proc 2.0`. Since it contains a character special to the shell (the `$`), Perl runs the command through the shell, so the shell gets a chance to expand that. Unless your environment contains the variable `proc`, that will expand to nothing. But that doesn't matter much, since the shell can't even seem to find the program `procheck` in the `PATH`. It complains about that.

If we change the quotes to double-quotes, the variable gets expanded by Perl (which is probably what you want, since you're using that variable in the loop). But then you're likely get a warning from Perl about not being able to find `procheck`.

The solution to that is to give the full path to the program, or make sure it's in the scripts `PATH`.

Though if running it on an interactive shell works, it's possible that `procheck` is actually an alias or a function. If it's just a regular executable, it would be in the `PATH`, which should be inherited to Perl and the subshell. In e.g. Bash, you could use `type -a procheck` to see what it actually runs and if there are other alternatives, like a disk file masked behind an alias.

---

Oh, also, if you don't need the shell when running the command, you can prevent Perl from even accidentally calling it by using the list form of `system` and giving the arguments to the command as separate arguments to `system`. Here, that would be `system("procheck",  $proc, "2.0")`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using single quotes.

Try this instead...

```
system ("procheck $proc 2.0");
```

Comment: If the `system()` function can't find the `procheck` executable with double quotes, then it won't find it with single quotes either.  This is not the problem that he OP is (currently) facing, but you're correct in that double quotes should be used to allow Perl to expand the `$proc` scalar.